# Integrate $2\int x^2\, \sec^2x \,\tan x\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

$$
2\int x^2\, \sec^2x \,\tan x\, \mathrm{d}x
$$

How to solve this using integration by parts? [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28x%5E2%29+%282sec%5E2+%28x%29%29+%28tan+x%29) can solve it, but is unable to give a step-by-step solution, and has a different answer to the one in the back of my textbook. There is also a question/answer on [yahoo answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080315122025AAcFr1k), but yet again, that gives a different answer to the one given to me.

Comment: Have u considered Integration by parts?

Comment: I have, but I am unable to integrate $sec^2 x \tan x$

Comment: @LordAro: See the answer and how to choose $dv$ for the first integration by parts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Integrate by parts, differentiating $x^2$ and integrating $\sec ^{2}x\tan x$ by substitution$^1$:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=&\int x^{2}\sec ^{2}x\tan x\, dx=\frac{1}{2}x^{2}\sec ^{2}x-\int x\sec
^{2}x\,dx \\
&=&\frac{1}{2}x^{2}\sec ^{2}x-\left( x\tan x-\int \frac{\sin x
}{\cos x}\,dx\right)\qquad \text{by parts; note }^2  \\
&=&\frac{1}{2}x^{2}\sec ^{2}x-x\tan x-\ln |\cos
x|+C.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
So
$$
\begin{equation*}
2I=2\int  x^{2}\sec ^{2}x\tan x dx=x^{2}\sec ^{2}x-2x\tan
x-2\ln | \cos x|+C. 
\end{equation*}
$$

--

$^1$ Let $u=\sec x$. Then $du=\sec x\, \tan x$ and

$$\int \sec ^{2}x\tan xdx=\int u\,du=\frac{1}{2}u^{2}=\frac{1}{2}\sec ^{2}x.$$

$^2$ Differentiate $x$ and integrate $\sec^2 x$. Since $\dfrac{d}{dx}\tan x=1+\tan ^{2}x=\sec ^{2}x$, $\displaystyle\int \sec ^{2}xdx=\tan x
$.

Comment: That looks good, but can you expand on the $\int sec^2 x tan x dx$ ? I'm not really sure where the $1/2 sec^2 x$ comes from

Comment: @LordAro We can integrate it by the substitution $u=\sec x$ (see edit).

Comment: great, thanks :) I think i'm going to have to revise the substitution method

Comment: @LordAro You are welcome.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Integrate by parts twice and in each case assume $u$ to be the polynomial function and consider $dv$ for the first integration by parts as  $$ dv = \sec(x) (\sec(x)\tan(x)) dx  \implies v = \frac{1}{2} \sec^2(x). $$

Can you finish it?